# AutoSuggestionBox ignore input (retain search query)

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, uwp-xaml

using an AutoSuggestionBox with MVVM I handle the `QuerySubmitted` Event in the ViewModel (using Behavior SDK for the binding). To make the UI more responsive to user input whenever the suggestion list is empty I add a single element with the text "Not suggestion found", or when the suggestions haven't loaded (from db or network) "Suggestions not yet loaded".

But I don't want users to be able to click these, because they are not really suggestions. In the event i can just return and do nothing, but the Box automatically takes the element and uses it for suggestion therefore deleting the previously typed text.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

this is the xaml:

```
<AutoSuggestBox x:Uid="StationSearch" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SuggestedStations}" Text="{Binding SearchQuery, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="QuerySubmitted">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadStationData}" InputConverter="{StaticResource SuggestionParameterConverter}" />
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</AutoSuggestBox>
```

and in the VM:

```
private void LoadStationData(Station selected)
{
    if (selected == _emptyStation || selected == _suggestionsNotLoadedStation)
    {
        return;
    }
    ... do more
}
// when looking for suggestions:
if(SuggestedStations.Count == 0)
    SuggestedStations.Add(_emptyStation);
```

Comment: Create a custom control derived fron AutoSuggestBox to achieve your target?